# Where is Actionsettings in TextRange2?

Tags: vba, hyperlink, powerpoint

I need to extract Hyperlinks from text Runs in PowerPoint 2007. I know I could do so using:
`TextFrame.TextRange.ActionSettings[PpMouseActivation.ppMouseClick].Hyperlink`

However, my code, which is quite lengthy, uses `TextFrame2` and its corresponding `TextRange2`, and I could not find `ActionSettings` in `TextRange2`.

Does anyone knows where it hides?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, it's a bit tricky. Here's how to get all of them:

```
Sub GetLinks()
    Dim p As Presentation
    Set p = ActivePresentation
    Dim s As Slide
    Dim sh As Shape
    For Each s In p.Slides
        For Each sh In s.Shapes
            Dim tr As TextRange
            Set tr = sh.TextFrame.TextRange
            For I = 1 To tr.Runs.count
                link = tr.Runs(I).ActionSettings(ppMouseClick).Hyperlink.Address
                If Len(link) > 0 Then
                    Debug.Print "Link: " & link
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but I specifically asked about TextFrame2 and TextRange2.

Comment: @Arie: `ActionSettings` doesn't exist for `TextRange2` - have you not consulted the Help file? There are only two reasons to use `TextFrame2` - 1) you're working with the active selected object and 2) you want access to PowerPoint 2007/2010 features. It doesn't sound like #2, so it must be #1. In that case, `TextFrame` can also be used against the `Selection` object, even side-by-side with `TextFrame2`.